# Nested resolves in UI Router not resolving

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm attempting to pass the results of UI-Router resolve to another resolve method in UI-Router but I find that any time I do this the following (nested) method fails to resolve.

The code below should resolve information about a user (called `SellerData` here), pass relevant parameters to an access check (called `SubscriptionId`) and the get some information using those two values (`sanitizedProduct`) All of this code independently works if I hardcode the results into the methods (ie replace `SellerData.product.id` with a value in `getSubscriptionId`) but as soon as I pass a resolved object the code fails and the resulting page never loads.

It's entirely possible I'm wrong about the nested nature of this stuff being an issue but I'm afraid I'm not seeing a ton of information about this issue so this is my best guess after spending quite a bit of time isolating stuff.

**UPDATE 3.19**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36126979/1888712) from Estus it's clear I'm making a mistake with promises (I had stupidly assumed resolve calls were synchronous) but the code is still not resolving properly. With this version both `SellerData` and `SubscriptionId` resolve properly and in the correct sequence but the `getSanitizedProduct` method is not called

```
.state('subscriberArea', {
    url: '/:creatorUsername/subscriber',
    templateUrl: 'modules/subscriber/client/views/subscriberArea.client.view.html',
    controller: 'SubscriberAreaController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',                 
    resolve: {
        SellerData: getSellerData,
        SubscriptionId: getSubscriptionId,
        sanitizedProduct: getSanitizedProduct,
    },
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Subscriber'
    }
})
```

Gets information about seller to be used in following methods and page binding

```
getSellerData.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'UserData', '$q', '_'];
function getSellerData($stateParams, UserData, $q, _){
    // Creates query to be passed to 'UserData' service that queries mongo
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var query = {'username': $stateParams.creatorUsername};
    return UserData.findOne(query).then(function(seller){
        // Adds essential information from query to new object that will be returned to the resovle
        var sellerData = {};
        sellerData._id = seller._id;
        sellerData.product.id = seller.product.id;  
        deferred.resolve(sellerData);
        return deferred.promise;
    });
}
```

Find if a value on the user object (known as Authentication) matches the product id resolved from getSellerData and set that value as the 'SubscriptionId' resolve

```
getSubscriptionId.$inject = ['Authentication', '_', '$q', 'SellerData'];
function getSubscriptionId(Authentication, _, $q, SellerData){
    var promises = [SellerData];
    $q.all(promises).then(function(resolved){
        var sellerData = resolved[0];
        var subscriptionId = _.intersection(Authentication.user.purchases, sellerData.product.id);
        deferred.resolve(subscriptionId);
        return deferred.promise;
    })
}
```

Query a database with the resolved SellerData and SubscriptionId information

```
getSanitizedProduct.$inject = ['ProductData', 'SellerData', 'SubscriptionId', '$q'];
function getSanitizedProduct(ProductData, SellerData, SubscriptionId, $q){
    var promises = [SellerData, SubscriptionId];
    $q.all(promises).then(function(resolved){
        var sellerData = resolved[0]
        var subscriptionId = resolved[1]
        var productId = sellerData.product.id;
        var versionId = {'version': subscriptionId};
        return ProductData.getWhitelistedData(productId, versionId).then(function(product){
            // plain() is a Restangular method that strips unnecessary properties
            return product.plain();
        });
    }
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

Basic UI-Router setup:

```
.state('subscriberArea', {
    url: '/:creatorUsername/subscriber',
    templateUrl: 'modules/subscriber/client/views/subscriberArea.client.view.html',
    controller: 'SubscriberAreaController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',                 
    resolve: {
        SellerData: getSellerData,
        SubscriptionId: getSubscriptionId,
        sanitizedProduct: getSanitizedProduct,
    },
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Subscriber'
    }
})
```

Gets information about seller to be used in following methods and page binding

```
getSellerData.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'UserData', '_'];
function getSellerData($stateParams, UserData, _){
    // Creates query to be passed to 'UserData' service that queries mongo
    var query = {'username': $stateParams.creatorUsername};
    return UserData.findOne(query).then(function(seller){
        // Adds essential information from query to new object that will be returned to the resovle
        var sellerData = {};
        sellerData._id = seller._id;
        sellerData.product.id = seller.product.id;
        return sellerData;
    });
}
```

Find if a value on the user object (known as Authentication) matches the product id resolved from getSellerData and set that value as the 'SubscriptionId' resolve

```
getSubscriptionId.$inject = ['Authentication', '_', 'SellerData'];
function getSubscriptionId(Authentication, _, SellerData){
    return _.intersection(Authentication.user.purchases, SellerData.product.id);
}
```

Query a database with the resolved SellerData and SubscriptionId information
    getProduct.$inject = ['ProductData', 'SellerData', 'SubscriptionId'];

```
function getSanitizedProduct(ProductData, SellerData, SubscriptionId){
    var productId = SellerData.product.id;
    var versionId = {'version': SubscriptionId};
    return ProductData.getWhitelistedData(productId, versionId).then(function(product){
        // plain() is a Restangular method that strips unnecessary properties
        return product.plain();
    });
}
```

Comment: Any errors when it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SellerData` and `SubscriptionId` are local dependencies, they are specific to route controller. Controller's local dependencies aren't available for injection application-wide, and resolvers aren't different in this respect. Route controller is the only place where route resolver can be injected.

Moreover, `resolve` is an object and not an array. This means that the order in which the resolvers will be executed is not guaranteed. Always use `$q.all` if the promises have to be *executed* in particular order, or a chain of them if they have to be *executed* and *settled* in particular order.

All of the resolvers (`SellerData`, `SubscriptionId`, `sanitizedProduct`) should become separate services (most likely `service` and not `factory`), and the last in the chain (`sanitizedProduct`) should be used as route resolver.

Comment: This was really helpful but I'm still having some issues. I'm new to UI-Router and it's just not sticking in my head. Would you mind taking a look at my updated post? I think I'm just overlooking something fundamental.

Comment: @brokyo As stated in the answer, *resolvers (SellerData, SubscriptionId, sanitizedProduct) should become separate services (most likely service and not factory)*. And currently they are not. So they cannot be injected into each other. And will throw injector errors. Make sure that you check the console for the errors, and listen to $stateChangeError events to log route resolver rejections.

Comment: Oh my apologies. I read that as a style suggestion rather than one necessary for things to work. Excuse what I'm sure is a stupid question but SellerData, for example, works in `getSubscriptionId` and I'm able to access the values. What is the reason for the injection working there but not elsewhere (I'm totally sure there is one I'm just trying to get my head around it!)

Comment: Also there are no console errors. I was under the impression that that was one of the drawbacks (http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/02/angularjs-pitfalls-using-ui-routers-resolve/) of using resolve. Should I be doing something other than just watching my browsers console? Thanks!